# What HTML elements might have browser set default padding/margin?

Tags: html, css

I know that `ol` and `ul` elements have default padding set on almost all browsers. Apparently `h{#}` tags do too on some browsers.

How do I get a list of all elements?

I could simply do `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` (which is my desired result), but that's simply bad.

Comment: If that is your desired result, why is using `*` bad?

Comment: Because this will apply this CSS rule to all DOM elements, even those that don't default to additional padding set by the browser.

Comment: No element defaults to "additional" padding set by the browser, they either default to some padding or no padding. If they start out at no padding, what is wrong with explicitly setting no padding on them?

Comment: @Quentin You have 5 kids. `a, b, c` male, `d, e` female. Doctor called you letting you know that girls need to get vaccinated from a girl only decease. Will you still take all five kids just in case? No: that will waste you more time, more resources. How is the `* {}` different?

Comment: Applying a CSS rule to HTML elements has negligible cost, will not cause HTML elements to feel pain and overuse has no chance of causing padding to develop a resistance to CSS.

Comment: [What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) It sounds like you should be using either [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), or possibly a generic CSS reset.

Comment: I want to learn about elements that I need to pay special attention when writing CSS code, esp. the most common ones. The amount of trolls on SOF got beyond of tolerable. Everyone seems to know an answer and down-vote anything that's "beyond my interest in solving this issue."

Comment: Well, [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/normalize.css) is a great place to start. It has comments explaining everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The W3C has a (informative, not normative) default stylesheet for HTML 4 here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

where you can see that no elements have padding, but body, h1..h6, p, fieldset, form, ul, ol, dl, dir, menu, blockquote and dd have a margin by default.

Comment: It's very much *informative* and significantly different from what most browsers use.

Comment: Yes. Also much _smaller_ than what most browsers use! I didn't say it was anywhere near perfect...

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat solved problem. You have two options:

1. A 'reset' stylesheet, one that removes all special styling (like padding and margin) from (almost all) elements, so you can start 'fresh'. You'll need to redefine things like `font-weight` for `<b>`old and `<strong>`. [Reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) is a popular choice.
2. A stylesheet that sets sensible defaults. This would, for example, remove paddings and margins, but then add them again so that browsers are consistent with each other. The stylesheet included in the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) can be stripped or used as-is for your purposes.

You can also use the above two stylesheets as a guide on what elements might have margins and paddings in different user agents and roll your own. In my opinion, setting sensible defaults (the second option) is better, since you might forget things like :focus styles with a plain 'reset stylesheet'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple CSS reset, a list of all resets: http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/10/23/a-killer-collection-of-global-css-reset-styles/

And you can get a look into a Useragent Stylesheet: http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/

But there are very much elements with padding/margin:

- `body`
- `blockquote`
- `dd`
- `p`
- ect.

Comment: Please don't advise people to use reset stylesheets.

Comment: @Guy Why is that and why didn't you downvote all the other answers too?

Comment: @Guy — Why not? Your question implies that you are trying to write one!

Comment: @Quentin Not at all. I am memorizing the most common ones.