# Why are there margins around my header when I've set width: 100%?

Tags: css, margin

First timer here. Could someone please tell me why there are margins around the header? How can I fix it?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lauriecai/39J2B/3/

```
header {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other CSS (e.g., in `index.html`)?

Comment: Here's my index.html:

!(http://i.imgur.com/ltK1MYT.png)

Comment: Yah, you should include the `index.html` file and any other files associated with it

Comment: You should edit your post with it.

Comment: Just added the screenshots.

Comment: Body has default padding inside it and your header is body minus padding. What you need is reset.css of somekind. Make your own to set EVERYTHING to have 0 margin and padding `* {margin:0;padding:0;}` or use [meyerweb reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you make a JSFiddle ?

Comment: That extra spacing **above** the header is making me scratch my head...

Comment: Ah found it. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually **two things** at work here.

### 1. Body margins

By default, the body has margins of around 5px(ish). Most of the answers on here have already covered that. You can fix it by setting them to 0;

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

### 2. `<h1>` ALSO has margins

Your header is being pushed down by the margins on your `<h1>` element. Remove the top margins to fix it.

```
h1
{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

### [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39J2B/2/)

Comment: Thanks! This got rid of the top margin. I didn't set any margins for <h1> though. Does everything have margins until you specify them to 0?

Comment: @Laurie No. Only certain elements have default margins. [**See this question for more**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428820/what-html-elements-might-have-browser-set-default-padding-margin) and please accept my answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

When posting to SO, you generally want to put your code into a

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net),

since it gives everyone the ability to easily access the code you've already written/attempted. Images are both tedious and difficult to work with and will probably deter people from helping you. I'd try to avoid them when you want to post code.

Nevertheless, the actual answer to your question:

If you want to remove all padding and margins, you should add the following CSS to your `index.css` file:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the advice! I've just created one and set up the code. Would I just post as a link? (http://jsfiddle.net/lauriecai/39J2B/)?

Comment: @Laurie Yes. If possible always post in a fiddle. It helps us help you better. A direct link is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<header>
<a href="index.html">
<h1>LAURIE</h1>
<h2>DESIGNER</h2>
</a>
</header>
</body>
```

css

```
/*general*/

body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

or

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
}
```

also `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

`<style>
html, body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
</style>`